# Scraping youtube to get dynamically loaded content

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape youtube but most of the times I do it, It just gives back an empty result. 
In this code snippet I'm trying to get the list of the video titles on the page. But when I run it I just get an empty result back. Even one title doesn't show up in result.
I've searched around and some results point out that it's due to the website loading content dynamically with javascript. Is this the case? How do I go about solving this? Is it possible to do without selenium?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/user/schafer5/videos').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

title = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class': "yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-grid-video-renderer")

print(title)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Is it possible to do without selenium?*

Often services have APIs which allow easier automation than scraping sites, Youtube has API and there are ready official libraries for various languages, for Python there is [google-api-python-client](https://pypi.org/project/google-api-python-client/), you would need key to use, to get running I suggest following [Youtube Data API quickstart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/python), note that you might ignore `OAuth 2.0` parts, as long as you need access only to public data.

Comment: Next time I'll definitely try searching for any APIs if they're available. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree with @Daweo and that's the right way to scrape a website like Youtube. But if you want to use BeautifulSoup and not get an empty list at the end, your code should be changed to as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/user/schafer5/videos').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
titles = [i.text for i in soup.findAll('a') if i.get('aria-describedby')]

print(titles)
```

I also suggest that you use the API.